# JQuery - Table align numeric column at right

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm making a dinamic table and i have a problem with my code. He is checking every TD and aligning it individuality.
I want to put a rule like this:

```
If (ThereIsAnyLetterInThisColumn) -> AlignAllThisColumnToLeft
```

Here is a Example Plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/5HtbKh8B1mJEk0yqQIkd?p=preview

In this example, for example, all values ​​must be left-aligned, because in the column there are numbers and letters. If the column were all numeric, it should be aligned to the right

Can anyone help me?

Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Define a class in CSS and assign it to each cell in the column

Comment: My table is generate dynamically, i can't put a css class, but thanks for anwser!

Comment: You have no CSS at all on your page? Do you use inline style everywhere?

Comment: Yes, i have, but the alignment is done by jquery

Comment: It seems you got me wrong. What I meant is: 1) define CSS class containing needed styles (alignment); 2) assign this class to each cell (by `addClass`)

Comment: Please provide all relevant code in an [mcve] in the question itself, not only on a third-party site.

Comment: Yes i have align classes with bootstrap, you can look in Plunker Example.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan i updated a new Plunker, now you can look a good example about my real code.

Comment: Maybe you should read my comment again, especially the second part, **in the question itself, not only on a third-party site**

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan I'm sorry, my english is not very good. I think i was not much clear... But now Rhea understood what I want! I have only one more problem, i'm waiting to her answer =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the third column, since there i 4s in the last row, ENITRE columnis aligned right.

the second column s aligned left since there is no letter

the first column is alinged right since all are letters.

```js
$('td').each(function(){
   if(isNaN($(this).text())){
    var idx = $(this).index();
    $('tr').each(function(){ $(this).children('td:eq('+idx+')').addClass('left-align');})
   } 
 });
```

```css
.left-align{ text-align:left;}
td{border:1px solid #ccc; text-align:right}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table width=500 cellborder=1>
<tr>
<td>one</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>4</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>two</td>
<td>2</td>
<td>4</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>three</td>
<td>3</td>
<td>4</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>four</td>
<td>4</td>
<td>4s</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Not working =( .
Same thing, the numbers are aligning to the right, but I want to put a condition that if 'Column' has
 A TD with a letter, that column line up to the right

Comment: @vitor sorry changed.

Comment: @Vitor now, even if ONE of the td contains a letter, ENTIRE column would be aligned right. is that what you want

Comment: ok, this is a good code, but it is checking Each TD, if a change for example the "one" and put a random number, it should be on the right, because is this column there is at least one TD letter, did you understand? Thanks =)

Comment: @Vitor no. `run the code snippet` what is it that you want

Comment: That's it! But on the contrary! Letters or Letters with numbers on Left, and Columns of Full Numbers on Right. I tried to change "if(isNaN($(this).text()))" to "if(!isNaN($(this).text()))", but didn't work =(

Comment: wasnt this happening by default? anyways edited the answer

Comment: that's it what i want! is totally correct! But now i have another problem =( . I'm using datatable, i'm sorry, I thought this would not be a problem. Here is an example for you: https://plnkr.co/edit/IXZfmXlTHe8RAMZminvY?p=preview

@Edit i put wrong link, now it's right!

Comment: u need to run this cde before it changes to datatable

Comment: Solved! Thanks a lot Rhea! You are my hero =) !

Answer (score 0):

I think this code should work for you.

```
$('td').each(function(){

    var text_td = $(this).html();

    if (text_td.indexOf('yourletter') > -1) {
        $(this).css('text-align','right');
    }        
}
```

Comment: Where have i put this? I can't understand so much your answer. Thanks for reply

Comment: @Vitor This is jquery code. You go over every td and you are taking each html content. If your letter is inside of this content, you align the text to right.

Comment: actually in this example the table was done manually but in my original code this table is received from a server, so I get every html content

Comment: Then execute this code when you receive the content from the server @Vitor